# Sends empty to PHP through post method

Tags: php, android

I am working with an Android project in which I need to connect with MySQL with PHP. For that I have used PHP post method to pass data from Android to PHP. My code is given below:

```
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
OutputStream outputStream=httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

BufferedWriter bufferedWriter=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
String post_data=URLEncoder.encode("mobile","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(mobile,"UTF-8")+"&"+
URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
// Toast.makeText(context,"after data pass",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
bufferedWriter.flush();
bufferedWriter.close();

InputStream inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
String result="";
String line="";
while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
    result += line;
}
bufferedReader.close();
inputStream.close();
httpURLConnection.disconnect();
return  result;
```

But the problem is in the PHP script. No data is passes, rather the PHP  script receives an empty string. Why this occurs? And what should be the solution for that?
My PHP code is:

```
<?php 
require "conn1.php"; 
$mobile= $_POST["mobile"]; 
$user_password= $_POST["password"]; 
$query="select * from pharmacytable where mobile like '$mobile' and PharPassword like '$user_password';"; 
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){ 
    echo "Login success"; 
} else{ 
    echo "Login failed"; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: How do you know that the php script receives an empty string? Please post the php script.

Comment: ++`return  result;`. Please tell the text of result.

Comment: `result += line;`. That should be `result += line + "\n"; `.

Comment: <?php 
require "conn1.php";
$mobile= $_POST["mobile"];
$user_password= $_POST["password"];
$query="select * from pharmacytable where mobile like '$mobile' and PharPassword like '$user_password';";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
 echo "Login success";
}
else{
 echo "Login failed";
}
?>

Comment: I have checked the $mobile and $user_password variable. but they show empty string

Comment: How did you check those variables? How do you know if they are set or what they contain? Please put your php code in a code block of your post. Not in a comment. You did not answer what you got in `result`  variable of `return result;`.

Comment: code is added to the code block.
I have get the message passed from php by and show a toast message. It shows that register failed. I also returned the data that the php accepted by post method. it shows an emptry string in toast. through this I have known that the php accepts an emptry string

Comment: `I have get the message passed from php by and show a toast message. It shows that register failed.`. Why are you so unclear? String result can contain 'Login failed' or 'Login success'. So we expect you to tell us what you received. Dont use vague terms like registering.

Comment: `I also returned the data that the php accepted by post method`. Well add that code. Show what you did exactly. Moreover there is no Toast in the code you posted hence you make it difficult for us to know where you are talking about.

Comment: Whats your problem man? Why are you make it so difficult? I have uploaded the java code as well as php code. I think thats enough for you if you know the answer. If you dont then dont talk too much.

Comment: I just told I pass some data from android to php bt the data doesnt go to php. It losses in somewhere. If yoi know the solution then reply me. Otherwise stop

Comment: You are pretty unfriendly to someone who tries to help you. I wonder why you dont answer my questions even if you find them difficult. They are not that difficult ;-).

Comment: Without a [mcve], your question is impossible to answer. greenapps is in the right here, you need to fix your question.